# When querying a Django model, is there a way to match every string in a field

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a lot of code that runs queries like the following:

```
User.objects.filter(town=selectedTown, gender="M").count();
```

if I were writing the mySQL statements, I could pass "%" as the value for selectedTown and it would match everything.  Is there a way I can achieve this in Django, not by modifying the query, but by passing in a wildcard string.

The reason is because I have large blocks of code that give me all kinds of statistics about users in whichever town I select.   I would also like there to be a "master" view where it shows users in every town, but I don't want to have to re-write all of the queries.

Thanks!

Comment: Match every string in the field - why don't provide the `town` argument in the first place? I am missing smth here.

Comment: If you're going to match every town, just remove `town` from the `.filter`.

Comment: @Joseph thats not really the point of my question.    I have a view that displays hundreds of statistics for each town.  I also want a "master" view that displays these stats for all users regardless of the town.  That is why most of the time, I do want the town to be passed in, but on rare occasion, I would like to pass something into that view that will match everything.

Comment: @user2662692 So use a different queryset in each case. If you're in the "master view", don't pass in town.

Comment: @Joseph the whole point of the question is that I am trying to avoid that.  I don't want to re-write hundreds of queries... it might not be possible, but I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better not to specify `town` filter at all:

```
User.objects.filter(gender="M").count();
```

For this you could use a dictionary to pass the keyword arguments:

```
def count_users(selectedTown=None):
    filters = {"gender": "M"}
    if selectedTown is not None:
        filters["town"] = selectedTown
    return User.objects.filter(**filters).count();
```

Comment: Awesome.  Did not know you could do this.